# CSS formatting in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My app in flutter gets from API Text Html and some have a CSS Style.
But, I don't know how I can handle CSS in Flutter.
My API body example:

```
 {
        "id": "165517",
        "prova_id": "27863318",
        "materia_id": "697",
        "tipo": "2",
        "pergunta": "Considerando-se a Lei nº 9.394/96, que estabelece as diretrizes e bases da educação nacional, relacione a COLUNA II com a COLUNA I, associando os componentes da Educação Básica aos enunciados correspondentes.<br><br>COLUNA I<br><br><ol class=\"orderedlist\"><li class=\"insertorderedlist2-bold\">Educação Infantil</li><li class=\"insertorderedlist2-bold\">Ensino Fundamental</li><li class=\"insertorderedlist2-bold\">Ensino Médio</li></ol><br>COLUNA II<br><br><table class=\"table-richtext\"><tbody class=\"pcss-165517-12\"><tr><td class=\"pcss-165517-14\">( )</td><td>Possui duração de nove anos, é gratuito na escola pública e inicia-se aos seis anos de idade.</td></tr><tr><td>( )</td><td>A preparação básica para o trabalho e a cidadania do educando, para que continue aprendendo, de modo a ser capaz de se adaptar com flexibilidade a novas condições de ocupação ou aperfeiçoamento posteriores, é uma de suas finalidades.</td></tr><tr><td>( )</td><td>A avaliação é realizada por acompanhamento e registro do desenvolvimento das crianças, sem o objetivo de promoção.</td></tr><tr><td>( )</td><td>Os currículos incluirão, obrigatoriamente,o estudo da língua inglesa e poderão ofertar outras línguas estrangeiras, em caráter optativo.</td></tr><tr><td>( )</td><td>O Ensino Religioso, de matrícula facultativa,é parte integrante da formação básica do cidadão nessa etapa da Educação Básica.</td></tr><tr><td>( ) </td><td>Atendimento à criança deve ser realizado durante, no mínimo, quatro horas diárias para o turno parcial, e durante sete horas para a jornada integral.</td></tr></tbody></table><br>Assinale a sequência correta.",
        "materia_desc": "Recursos Multifuncionais",
        "texto_id": null,
        "texto_assoc": null,
        "alts": "[{\"id\": 713826, \"letra\": \"a\", \"conteudo\": \"2 2 1 3 3 1\"}, {\"id\": 713827, \"letra\": \"b\", \"conteudo\": \"1 2 3 2 1 3\"}, {\"id\": 713828, \"letra\": \"c\", \"conteudo\": \"3 2 1 1 3 2\"}, {\"id\": 713829, \"letra\": \"d\", \"conteudo\": \"2 3 1 3 2 1<br>\"}]",
```

My API  results:

Large Space...

[image: API Results]

I use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html, but this pack don't support "CSS Attributes" =(
How is the best way to decode HTML with CSS attributes from API? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The css part might be parsable with https://pub.dev/packages/csslib.